# How can I find out what is taking up space on my hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, space

I have a tiny hard drive - 128 GB. I am not that technical. I see that other files under storage is taking up say 40 GB of space. My boyfriend got me a WD NAS hard drive and I was able to move my photos from iPhoto, and iTunes, there to free up some space.

I accidentally deleted iPhoto so in order to install it.

My boyfriend showed me a script that showed the size of some big directories.

> .3G   /Applications/iMovie 9.0.9/iMovie 9.0.9.app/Contents/Resources
>
> 1.3G  /Applications/iMovie 9.0.9/iMovie 9.0.9.app/Contents
>
> 1.3G  /Applications/iMovie 9.0.9/iMovie 9.0.9.app
>
> 1.3G  /Applications/iMovie 9.0.9
>
> 2.0G  /Applications/iMovie.app/Contents
>
> 2.0G  /Applications/iMovie.app
>
> 5.3G  /Applications/Install OS X Yosemite.app/Contents/SharedSupport
>
> 5.3G  /Applications/Install OS X Yosemite.app/Contents
>
> 5.3G  /Applications/Install OS X Yosemite.app
>
> 1.1G  /Applications/iPhoto.app/Contents/Resources
>
> 1.3G  /Applications/iPhoto.app/Contents
>
> 1.3G  /Applications/iPhoto.app
>
> 1.0G  /Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Office
>
> 1.2G  /Applications/Microsoft Office 2011

Can i delete the iMovie directory and maybe download it at a later time?

Is there a better way to figure out where all the space is being taken up?

Like lets say I had an 18 GB zip file saved on my desktop. Theoretically that would be under the other space category but OS X isn't helping make me aware of that file. How do I find big files like that? Mind you i don't have a 18 GB zip file sitting around but I am trying to find if I have any big files sitting around to delete.

Comment: You can use iCloud for free, the Google drive for free to upload your stuff and free some space.

Comment: Are you using Yosemite? One thing you can delete is the Install OS X Yosemite.app bundle.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend using:  http://daisydiskapp.com

.. Once downloaded and installed they have a "Test Drive" option you click that lets you use it for free.  Please note that to see *all* files on your HD that all users own, you will want to use the "Scan as Administrator" option, which will prompt you to enter your password.

There is also:

- Disk Inventory X - http://www.derlien.com
- Disk Map - Google for "Disk Map OS X" ( Commercial software )

Comment: 'Disk Inventory X' has later become 'Grand Perspective'

Comment: Ah, thank you @CousinCocaine - Link for Grand Perspective is http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I use Grand Perspective for checking what is hogging disk space. Its a good visual tool - try it out - http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

## du

You can use the commandline to help you out with this. I prefer a one-liner such as this one:

```
sudo du -h /Users 2>/dev/null | grep '^\s*[0-9]\+G'
```

This might be intimidating in the beginning, but it is fairly simple. You can find an explanation on what each part does here: [explainshell.com](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=sudo+du+-h+%2FUsers+2%3E%2Fdev%2Fnull+%7C+grep+%27%5E%5Cs*%5B0-9%5D%5C%2BG%27). But in short, it uses a user with admin rights to check the size of each file in `/Users`, only the files starting that are more than 1GB are reported back to the user.

Output looks like this:

```
 12G    /Users/SisterMorphine
 11G    /Users/CousinCocaine/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/36f7b86ae0c012ea81226714036c4453ad86e67a
 11G    /Users/CousinCocaine/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup
 11G    /Users/CousinCocaine/Library/Application Support/MobileSync
 19G    /Users/CousinCocaine/Library/Application Support
 29G    /Users/CousinCocaine/Library
 45G    /Users/CousinCocaine
 11G    /Users/PabloPicasso/Library
 12G    /Users/PabloPicasso/Pictures/PabloPicasso 2015.photoslibrary/Masters/2015/05/16/20150516-111947
 21G    /Users/PabloPicasso/Pictures/PabloPicasso 2015.photoslibrary/Masters/2015/05/16
 24G    /Users/PabloPicasso/Pictures/PabloPicasso 2015.photoslibrary/Masters/2015/05
 36G    /Users/PabloPicasso/Pictures/PabloPicasso 2015.photoslibrary/Masters/2015
 36G    /Users/PabloPicasso/Pictures/PabloPicasso 2015.photoslibrary/Masters
 37G    /Users/PabloPicasso/Pictures/PabloPicasso 2015.photoslibrary
 37G    /Users/PabloPicasso/Pictures
 53G    /Users/PabloPicasso
110G    /Users
```

Comment: Offcouse you can choose the run the same command on `/` or `/Applications`